# MEAN Stack - Mongo Data onto Angular Gives Unwanted Result

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

So I've been working on a side-project to get more familiar with the MEAN environment, and I have come to a brick-wall that has been blocking me for a few days now.

My problem is this:
When I pull the count of my MongoDB, it displays on the page with no problem.
But when I want to display data from my DB in a 2-column table, I can't. Mongo is returning my Database as a giant JSON document. I want to be able to have a table that contains the `name` and the `total` for each document in the mongo collection `heroes`.

Can anyone help me? I've been scouring the web for days now and want to at least get past this test.

Here are my files:

-- SNIPPET FROM SERVER.JS --

```
//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dota2');
var db =  mongoose.connection;
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://****:*****@ds033469.mongolab.com:33469/dota2');
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
db.once('open', function callback(){
    console.log("Connection to Mongo database opened");
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var heroSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        initiator: Number,
        disabler: Number,
        pusher: Number,
        jungler: Number,
        nuker: Number,
        slug: String,
        lanesupport: Number,
        escape: Number,
        carry: Number,
        total: Number,
        support: Number,
        melee: Number
    }, 
    {collection: 'heroes'});

//Pulling out a piece of data and putting it into an object for Angular
var heroModel = mongoose.model('name:', heroSchema, 'heroes');


var heroData;
heroModel.find('name',{'name':'', _id:0}, function(err, herodatagrab) {
    if(err);
    heroData = herodatagrab;
});

//Show that Dota2/heroes has documents within.
var heronumber;
heroModel.count({ }, function (err, heroNumObj) {
  if (err);
  heronumber = heroNumObj;
});


//Catch-Partials
app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});


//Catch-All route
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        heroData: heroData,
        heronumber: heronumber
    });
});
```

-- INDEX.JADE --

```
extends ../includes/layout
title = {title}
block main-content
    section.content
        div(ng-view)
    h3=heronumber 
        |  heroes in the database

block hero
    section.content
        div(ng-view)
    h3=heroData
```

--RESULT AS IT APPEARS ON THE PAGE--

102 heroes in the database

> { name: 'Abaddon' },{ name: 'Alchemist' },{ name: 'Ancient
>   Apparition' },{ name: 'Anti-mage' },{ name: 'Axe' },{ name: 'Bane' },{
>   name: 'Batrider' },{ name: 'Beastmaster' },{ name: 'Bloodseeker' },{
>   name: 'Bounty Hunter' },{ name: 'Brewmaster' },{ name: 'Bristleback'
>   },{ name: 'Broodmother' },{ name: 'Centaur Warrunner' },{ name: 'Chaos
>   Knight' },{ name: 'Chen' },{ name: 'Clinkz' },{ name: 'Clockwerk' },{
>   name: 'Crystal Maiden' },{ name: 'Dark Seer' },{ name: 'Dazzle' },{
>   name: 'Death Prophet' },{ name: 'Disruptor' },{ name: 'Doom' },{ name:
>   'Dragon Knight' },{ name: 'Drow Ranger' },{ name: 'Earthshaker' },{
>   name: 'Elder Titan' },{ name: 'Enchantress' },{ name: 'Enigma' },{
>   name: 'Faceless Void' },{ name: 'Gyrocopter' },{ name: 'Huskar' },{
>   name: 'Invoker' },{ name: 'IO' },{ name: 'Jakiro' },{ name:
>   'Juggernaut' },{ name: 'Keeper of the Light' },{ name: 'Kunkka' },{
>   name: 'Leshrac' },{ name: 'Lich' },{ name: 'Lifestealer' },{ name:
>   'Lina' },{ name: 'Lion' },{ name: 'Lone Druid' },{ name: 'Luna' },{
>   name: 'Lycanthrope' },{ name: 'Magnus' },{ name: 'Medusa' },{ name:
>   'Meepo' },{ name: 'Mirana' },{ name: 'Morphling' },{ name: 'Naga
>   Siren' },{ name: 'Nature\'s Prophet' },{ name: 'Necrolyte' },{ name:
>   'Night Stalker' },{ name: 'Nyx Assassin' },{ name: 'Ogre Magi' },{
>   name: 'Omniknight' },{ name: 'Outworld Devourer' },{ name: 'Phantom
>   Assassin' },{ name: 'Phantom Lancer' },{ name: 'Puck' },{ name:
>   'Pudge' },{ name: 'Pugna' },{ name: 'Queen of Pain' },{ name: 'Razor'
>   },{ name: 'Riki' },{ name: 'Rubick' },{ name: 'Sand King' },{ name:
>   'Shadow Demon' },{ name: 'Shadow Fiend' },{ name: 'Shadow Shaman' },{
>   name: 'Silencer' },{ name: 'Skeleton King' },{ name: 'Skywrath Mage'
>   },{ name: 'Slardar' },{ name: 'Slark' },{ name: 'Sniper' },{ name:
>   'Spectre' },{ name: 'Spirit Breaker' },{ name: 'Storm Spirit' },{
>   name: 'Sven' },{ name: 'Templar Assassin' },{ name: 'Tidehunter' },{
>   name: 'Timbersaw' },{ name: 'Tinker' },{ name: 'Tiny' },{ name:
>   'Treant Protector' },{ name: 'Troll Warlord' },{ name: 'Tusk' },{
>   name: 'Undying' },{ name: 'Ursa' },{ name: 'Vengeful Spirit' },{ name:
>   'Venomancer' },{ name: 'Viper' },{ name: 'Visage' },{ name: 'Warlock'
>   },{ name: 'Weaver' },{ name: 'Windrunner' },{ name: 'Witch Doctor' },{
>   name: 'Zeus' }

Thank you for any help that you can give. This is getting really frustrating!

Comment: How are you making the request in Angular? Are you using `$http`? Once you get the response, are you setting it to a variable on your `$scope`? How are you binding to that variable in your view? Are you using `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

You are just rendering the text representation of your `heroData` object.

At least, you need to place `heroData` in the **script tag** and use angular's expression to print it. Something like that:

```
script.
    var heroes = heroData;
    // put heroes into $scope 

div {{heroes}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular, you can use the `$http` or `$resource` for data source, and set a api endpoint for data output.

If you want display the result in jade file, you can use the `each ... in ...` to display the data:

```
table
  tr
    th Name
    th Total
  each hero in heros
    tr
      td= hero.name
      td= hero.total
```